# Can't push commits to Pull Request in GitHub

Tags: github, git-commit, pull-request, branching-and-merging

I set up an private free github repo to work on a project with my friends. I set up a branch protection rule as you can see in listing 1. So when I want to push new commits to my pull request I get an error.

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/neo-14-block-prefab-hp-system.        
remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.        
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:robinsadeghpour/nogame_prototypes.git'
To github.com:robinsadeghpour/nogame_prototypes.git
!   refs/heads/neo-14-block-prefab-hp-system:refs/heads/neo-14-block-prefab-hp-system   [remote rejected] (protected branch hook declined)
```

How can I enable pushing commits to my open pull request?

[branch protection rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYMPV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can commit only to a non protected branch. Create a new branch and push your changes, then create a new pull request to the branch you want to merge with.